# restrict 1 word as case sensitive and other as case insensitive in python regex | (pipe)

Tags: python, regex

I got the meaning of `|` (pipe special character) in regex, Python.
It matches either 1st or 2nd.

ex : `a|b`  Matches either a or b.

**My question:**
What if I want to match is `a` with case sensitive  and `b` with case insensitive in above example?

ex:

```
s = "Welcome to PuNe, Maharashtra"

result1 = re.search("punnee|MaHaRaShTrA",s)
result2 = re.search("pune|maharashtra",s)
result3 = re.search("PuNe|MaHaRaShTrA",s)
result4 = re.search("P|MaHaRaShTrA",s)
```

I want to search Pune in the way I have written in above statement `s` i.e `PuNe`. But I have to search Maharashtra by ignoring case. How can I search 1 word with case sensitive and other with case insensitive? So that, `result1`, `result2`, `result3`, `result4` will give `not null` value.

**I tried**:

```
result1 = re.search("pune|MaHaRaShTrA",s1, re.IGNORECASE)
```

But this ignores the cases for both the words.

How can I restrict 1 word as case sensitive and other as case insensitive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Python 3.6 and later, you may use the [inline modifier groups](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html):

```
>>> s = "Welcome to PuNe, Maharashtra"
>>> print(re.findall(r"PuNe|(?i:MaHaRaShTrA)",s))
['PuNe', 'Maharashtra']
```

See the relevant [Python `re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html):

> `(?aiLmsux-imsx:...)`
>    (Zero or more letters from the set `'a'`, `'i'`, `'L'`, `'m'`, `'s'`, `'u'`, `'x'`, optionally followed by `'-'` followed by one or more letters from the `'i'`, `'m'`, `'s'`, `'x'`.) The letters set or remove the corresponding flags: [`re.A`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.A) (ASCII-only matching), [`re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.I) (ignore case), [`re.L`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.L) (locale dependent), [`re.M`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.M) (multi-line), [`re.S`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.S) (dot matches all), `re.U` (Unicode matching), and [`re.X`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.X) (verbose), for the part of the expression. (The flags are described in [Module Contents](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#contents-of-module-re).)
>
> The letters `'a'`, `'L'` and `'u'` are mutually exclusive when used as inline flags, so they can’t be combined or follow `'-'`. Instead, when one of them appears in an inline group, it overrides the matching mode in the enclosing group. In Unicode patterns `(?a:...)` switches to ASCII-only matching, and `(?u:...)` switches to Unicode matching (default). In byte pattern `(?L:...)` switches to locale depending matching, and `(?a:...)` switches to ASCII-only matching (default). This override is only in effect for the narrow inline group, and the
>   original matching mode is restored outside of the group.
>  
>   *New in version 3.6.
>  
>  Changed in version 3.7: The letters
>   'a', 'L' and 'u' also can be used in a group.*

Unfortunately, Python `re` versions before 3.6 did not support these groups, nor did they support alternating on and off inline modifiers.

If you can use [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/), you may use a `(?i:...)` construct:

```
import regex
s = "Welcome to PuNe, Maharashtra"
print(regex.findall(r"PuNe|(?i:MaHaRaShTrA)",s))
```

See the [online Python demo](http://rextester.com/MGZFQ26067).

Comment: This is the simplest one.. and worked as I wanted .. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the lower/upper case regex for the second word, and keep casing active:

```
my_regex = "PuNe|"+"".join("[{}{}]".format(x.upper(),x.lower()) for x in "MaHaRaShTrA")
```

that generates: `PuNe|[Mm][Aa][Hh][Aa][Rr][Aa][Ss][Hh][Tt][Rr][Aa]`

and `re.search(my_regex,s1)` without any option does what you want.