# How to clear flags specified in regular expression in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

Consider the following regular expression in Golang:

```
'(?i)(facebook|fb)(.{0,20})?(?-i)[\'\\"][0-9a-f]{32}[\'\\"]'
```

It sets the case-insensitive flag (`(?i)`) and then later unsets it (`(?-i)`).

The above syntax for unsetting flags doesn't work in Python 3, and specifying the `(?i)` flag within a subgroup `((?i)...)` results in:

`<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Flags not at the start of the expression 'foo((?i)bar)'`

How can I clear flags specified within a regular expression in Python 3 (or only specify flags for a certain part of the regular expression, e.g. a subgroup)?

Comment: Use an inline modifier group, `'(?i:(facebook|fb)(.{0,20})?)[\'"][0-9a-f]{32}[\'"]'` ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44906025/3832970))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thank you. Do you know why that isn't mentioned in `pydoc3 re`?

Comment: It is, search for `(?aiLmsux-imsx:...)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I don't see it. Which verison of Python 3 are you using? For my 3.8.7 installation, only "`(?aiLmsux) The letters set the corresponding flags defined below.`" is present in `pydoc3 re`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kCfe2KU

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks, guess `pydoc3` doesn't reflect what's available on in the web  docs.