# Regex expressions - Deprecation warning

Tags: python, regex, deprecation-warning

The following fragment of code comes from my github repository found [here](https://github.com/cinephos/GBX-data-extraction/blob/main/gbx-retrieve.py).
It opens a binary file, and extracts the text within <header> tags. These are the crucial lines:

```
gbxfile = open(filename,'rb') 
gbx_data = gbxfile.read()
gbx_header = b'(<header)((?s).*)(</header>)'
header_intermediate = re.findall(gbx_header, gbx_data)
```

The script works BUT it receives the following Deprecation Warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Flags not at the start of the expression b'(<header)((?s).*)(</' (truncated)
  header_intermediate = re.findall(gbx_header, gbx_data)
```

What is the correct use of the regular expression in `gbx_header`, so that this warning is not displayed?

Comment: Just move the `(?s)` to the beginning of the regex i.e. `(?s)(<header)(.*)(</header>)`

Comment: It was so simple... and it works!!! Thank you!

Comment: No worries - glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Python bug tacker Issue 39394](https://bugs.python.org/issue39394), the warning was introduced in Python 3.6.

The point is that the Python `re` now does not allow using inline modifiers not at the start of string. In Python 2.x, you can use your pattern without any problem and warnings as `(?s)` is silently applied to the whole regular expression under the hood. Since it is not always an expected behavior, the Python developers decided to produce a warning.

Note you can use inline modifier groups in Python `re` now, see [restrict 1 word as case sensitive and other as case insensitive in python regex | (pipe)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44906025/3832970).

So, the solutions are

- Putting `(?s)` (or any other inline modifier) at the start of the pattern: `(?s)(<header)(.*)(</header>)`
- Using the `re` option, `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` instead of `(?s)`, `re.I` / `re.IGNORECASE` instead of `(?i)`, etc.
- Using workarounds (instead of `.`, use `[\w\W]`/`[\d\D]`/`[\s\S]` if you do not want to use `(?s)` or `re.S`/`re.DOTALL`).

Comment: Thank you! The problem of a modifier that works but points a finger to the programmer, is the least important problem of a script. And psychology does the rest. It was clear to me that the modifier `(?s)` should preceed the expression, but in a three part expression `b'[(start_of_text)(?text_to_retrieve)(end_of text)]`, it was not clear where was the beginning of the regex. And it is not easy to find online an example that matched my criteria. I hope that this post helps other programmers to solve a similar silly problem!