# How to use Python's regex to match a GPG signature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re, gpg-signature

I am trying to see if I can match the gpgsig using the regex below, but ran into an error also shown below.

Is there any guidance on how to fix it?

```
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = '''
tree e76fa5ccd76492d843b6a4a06038d1c3b5aef6f8
parent 0d533a3a5fd51fd8c2x932832ef9ea91d0756c18
author firstname lastname <userid@company.com> 1676061999 -0800
committer firstname lastname <userid@company.com> 1676061999 -0800
gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE-----
 MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCABgkqhkiG9w0B
 BwEAAKCCAuswggLnMIICjKADAgECAhANVjmYTunVjjNs9EhuJ4YXMAoGCCqGSM49
 BAMCME0xKTAnBgNVBAMMIEFmorplIENvcnBvcmF0ZSBTaWduaW5nIEVDQyBDQSAx
 MRMwEQYDVQQKDApBcHBsZSBJbmMuMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzAeFw0yMzAyMDkxOTU2
 NTlaFw0yMzAzMDIyMDA2NTlaMDIxEzARBgNVBAoMCkFmorplIEluYy4xGzAZBgNV
 BAMMEmduYWtrYWxhQGFmorplLmNvbTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IA
 BGwmvh7HYXCyerdERaLr+OOJ3AQxYNSfUorWkROO2xv/ra8yYGL/aBCYJSQUoYRY
 kY4GE90s8NAUwmQmsthdbFSjggFnMIIBYzAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB8GA1UdIwQY
 MBaAFEJi3AGoy1MCpVzt8IjG9uFJdhE9MHMGCCsGAQUFBwEBBGcwZTAvBggrBgEF
 BQcwAoYjaHR0cDovL2NlcnRzLmFmorplLmNvbS9hY3NlY2NhMS5kZXIwMgYIKwYB
 BQUHMAGGJmh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmFmorplLmNvbS9vY3NwMDMtYWNzZWNjMTA0MB0G
 A1UdEQQWMBSBEmduYWtrYWxhQGFmorplLmNvbTAUBgNVHSUEDTALBgkqhkiG92Nk
 BBQwMgYDVR0fBCswKTAnoCWgI4YhaHR0cDovL2NybC5hcHBsZS5jb20vYWNzZWNj
 YTEuY3JsMB0GA1UdDgQWBBR1dRRNvQ/7RwRTorG97HmKR4xoJjAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E
 BAMCB4AwJQYDVR0gBB4wHDAMBgoqhkiG92NkBRQBMAwGCiqGSIb3Y2QFFAIwCgYI
 KoZIzj0EAwIDSQAwRgIhAPQ4IiaCG6V5A7u0lwbhJxyXHf9jN2IoqRLj7BlFo4Uv
 AiEAtJAekfgFoiE3h8ZZDgvhwRiwPJseo8GDfM0tb5DP0h8xggE3MIIBMwIBATBh
 ME0xKTAnBgNVBAMMIEFmorplIENvcnBvcmF0ZSBTaWduaW5nIEVDQyBDQSAxMRMw
 EQYDVQQKDApBcHBsZSBJbmMuMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUwIQDVY5mE7p1Y4zbPRIbieG
 FzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFAKBpMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJ
 KoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTIzMDIxMDIwNDY1MFowLwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMSIEIP8j8iYG
 Ggpc74AeVdxLkIArVBLw3+vw6/FVmGtNig+uMAkGByqGSM49AgEERjBEAiB0dBI3
 9c1b/bsStaT3blWb19ehQDt8J/NNov/TzSgEzAIgWvpSs/DZI7wmlHtIJ8HpmIp4
 +oNOu4kJJlhtUy9ZImUAAAAAAAA=
 -----END SIGNED MESSAGE-----

'''

pattern = "gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE------{3,}$(?s).*?^-{3,} -----END SIGNED MESSAGE-----"

if re.search(pattern,log):
    print ("Found a match")
```

Here is the error:

```
/Users/Documents/pythonscripts/test.py:40: DeprecationWarning: Flags not at the start of the expression 'gpgsig -----BEGIN SI' (truncated)
  if re.search(pattern,log):
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex expressions - Deprecation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284064/regex-expressions-deprecation-warning)

Comment: It's not clear what you expect as an answer here. If your question is about the _warning_ message, then that's explained in [the proposed related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284064/regex-expressions-deprecation-warning). It's a _deprecation warning_ , which shouldn't be directly related to the matching of the pattern. Or, is your question about _not finding a match_ given your regex pattern? Then that's a different thing, indicating your regex pattern is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As previously commented, the `DeprecationWarning` is not an error but rather a warning, and under normal circumstances should not stop code execution (so I'll address it only later). Assuming the desired result is to match the `log` variable as provided, there are two problems with the pattern; matching dashes, and using the start/end (`^` and `$`) markers.

The amount of dashes tested by the pattern exceeds the amount of dashes in the `log` variable due to the [curly-bracket syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), so no match is found. Effectively, the pattern `gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE------{3,}` would only match similar text where the amount of dashes after `MESSAGE` is 8 or higher (where in `log` there are only 5 dashes):

```
>>> pattern = "gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE------{3,}"
>>> re.search(pattern, "gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE-------")
>>> re.search(pattern, "gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE--------")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 40), match='gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE--------'>
>>> re.search(pattern, "gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE-----------------")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 49), match='gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE----------------->
```

Additionally, to facilitate the use of start/end markers, the [MULTILINE flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) should be provided.
Adjusting the code as follows should match the contents in `log`:

```
pattern = "gpgsig -{3,}BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE-{3,}$(?s).*?^ -{3,}END SIGNED MESSAGE-{3,}"

if re.search(pattern, log, flags=re.MULTILINE):
    print("Found a match")
```

Execution result (note that while the warning is still emitted, now a match is actually found):

```
$ python /tmp/test.py
/tmp/test.py:40: DeprecationWarning: Flags not at the start of the expression 'gpgsig -{3,}BEGIN SI' (truncated)
  if re.search(pattern, log, flags=re.MULTILINE):
Found a match
```

---

As for the emitted warning, it relates to the inline modifier group `(?s)`, as its python implementation/interpretation might not yield the expected result. I can think of 3 ways to avoid this warning, but each one should be carefully examined to see if it fits your use-case (if at all);

1. Limit the inline modifier to a specific pattern:

```
pattern = "gpgsig -{3,}BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE-{3,}$(?s:.*)?^ -{3,}END SIGNED MESSAGE-{3,}"
```

2. Move the inline modifier to the start of the pattern:

```
pattern = "(?s)gpgsig -{3,}BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE-{3,}$.*?^ -{3,}END SIGNED MESSAGE-{3,}"
```

3. Use the [appropriate re flags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) (`re.S` or `re.DOTALL`) instead of the inline modifier:

```
pattern = "gpgsig -{3,}BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE-{3,}$.*?^ -{3,}END SIGNED MESSAGE-{3,}"
if re.search(pattern, log, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL):
    print("Found a match")
```

Comment: I want an exact match of `gpgsig -----BEGIN SIGNED MESSAGE-----` and  `-----END SIGNED MESSAGE-----` ,how does regex change for this?